# Lock Mac without turning off the screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, screen-lock

I have observed that the screen on my MacBook Pro turns off a few seconds after I activate lock screen.

Is there any way to keep the screen of my MacBook Pro on for an unlimited duration of time after I lock the screen? Or at least an hour as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, same question. Surprisingly little info out there about this. It seems to turn off after 10 seconds of locking the screen by default.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[KeepingYouAwake](https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake) is a free and open source app that can be used for this purpose.

The intended purpose of this app is to prevent your Mac from going into sleep. You can activate this app from 5/15/30 **minutes** to 1/2/5 **hours** to **indefinite** duration.

Having KeepingYouAwake activated will prevent screen from turning off when lock screen mode is activated.

KeepingYouAwake can be easily installed using Homebrew by running the following command:

`brew install --cask keepingyouawake`

Comment: Brilliant! It works!

Comment: Works, thank you! Make sure the cup is lit up (activated), I thought it wasn't working until I clicked on the icon.

Comment: I did it with with `brew install keepingyouawake`.

Comment: The new syntax should be `brew install --cask keepingyouawake`

Comment: You can also use the built in macOS command `caffeinate`, which has different but similar options.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I used the free app [Amphetamine](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12) from the app store.
After installing, I selected the indefinitely option to keep the screen for awake forever. I locked the screen and the screen is still on.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Posting [@calum_b](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2841/calum-b) and [@abhishek-kashyap](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/349376/abhishek-kashyap) answer here. This information deserves to be in the answers section not in comments. This is the way to do it without installing any package. Utilizes a built-in macOS utility.

```
 caffeinate -d
```

Here is the manual: https://ss64.com/osx/caffeinate.html

Answer (score 1):

On Mojave 10.14, I try this

- Install Caffeine to activate for indefinitely.
- In 'System Preference'->'Security & Privacy'->'General', check 'Require password...' and set to 1 minutes (anything that is not 'immediately')
- In 'System Preference'->'Energy Saver', set 'Turn display off..' to never and check 'Prevent computer from sleeping...'
- using screen saver activated by 'System Preference'->'Desktop & Screen Saver'->'Screen Saver'->'Hot Corners' and set one of the corner to start screen saver.

Then, activate the screen saver by moving mouse to the chosen corner.

This seems to help me.

Comment: You can also just use the built in macOS command `caffeinate`, which has similar options.

Answer (score 1):

Hey everyone I know I'm late here but I just switched from a macbook pro (where this issue doesnt exist) to a mac studio and this thing keeps going to sleep after 30 seconds when I lock the screen.

[@takobaba](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/206996/takobaba) answer helped me a lot but, adding an `&` at the end allows it to run in the background so you dont need to keep a terminal window open

full command is
`caffeinate -d &`

now just need a way to run this on startup and we are golden.